# ACF Field Type Post Object to only show only top level parent pages from a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm attempting to show only parent pages of a custom post type using Advanced Custom Fields Post Object field. Then I'm using Advanced Forms to show the form on the front-end. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how show only parent pages from a custom post type.

Currently, it is outputting all posts, pages and custom post types pages on the front-end:
!https://i.ibb.co/tXkxFdY/Screen-Shot-2019-04-01-at-2-50-25-PM.png

For reference, here is how my Post Object settings is set up in the ACF Pro plug-in:
!https://i.ibb.co/Z6W3cjF/Screen-Shot-2019-04-01-at-2-44-24-PM.png

I tried using the following the ACF Post Object query from:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-post_object-query/

Using the ACF page "acf/fields/post_object/query"
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-post_object-query/

I tried using the following:

```
function my_relationship_query( $args, $field, $post_id ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $post_id, // updated to use the current $post_id
        'post_type'   => 'mediakit', 
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'published' 
    );

    return;

}

// filter for every field
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/key=field_5ca24f099f985', 'my_relationship_query', 10, 3);
```

I was hoping the results on the front-end would show the select showing only parent pages of the custom post type, on the front-end.

The actual results is showing all the posts, pages and all the pages in the custom post type.

Any help on this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can use the ACF query filter to have the parent pages of a custom post type show up. When I go to the field to select my post type, the parents only show up in the Post Object dropdown.

Using this ACF official guide:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-post_object-query/

```
add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query/key=field_0000000000000', 'change_posts_order', 10, 3);
function change_posts_order( $args, $field, $post ) {

    $args['post_parent'] = 0;
    $args['sort_order'] = 'ASC';
    $args['orderby'] = 'title';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    return $args;
}
```